# Android Studio: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect?

Tags: android-studio, пароль

Подскажите, почему когда я в android studio на windows 10 пытаюсь создать apk с сертификатом, созданным ранее на Mac os x, у меня выдает ошибку:

> Cannot load key store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Пароль правильный. На mac os x он подходит.

Comment: Пароль латиницей или использует кириллические символы?

Comment: @Barmaley латиница

Comment: Вы вводите пароль из консоли или через UI студии?

Comment: @Barmaley из самой студии, когда пытаюсь создать signed APK и выбрать нужный alias из списка.

Comment: @Barmaley когда в консоли с этим сертификатом и паролем ввожу "c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -keystore path_xxxx то все ок, нет ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

> когда в консоли с этим сертификатом и паролем ввожу "c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -keystore path_xxxx то все ок, нет ошибки.

Это означает, что ошибка видимо, возникает из-за неверной интерпретации клавиатурных кодов в под различными осями в самой UI Студии (то бишь IDEA)

Надо выставить баг в [багтрекере Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html)